# CPU warning - abrt-watch-log

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am running a **Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.1 (Maipo)** on **Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5690  @ 3.47GHz**

I keep getting this error in `abrt-watch-log`.

```
root       888     1  0 Aug03 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/abrt-watch-log -F BUG: WARNING: at WARNING: CPU: INFO: possible recursive locking detected ernel BUG at list_del corruption list_add corruption do_IRQ: stack overflow: ear stack overflow (cur: eneral protection fault nable to handle kernel ouble fault: RTNL: assertion failed eek! page_mapcount(page) went negative! adness at NETDEV WATCHDOG ysctl table check failed : nobody cared IRQ handler type mismatch Machine Check Exception: Machine check events logged divide error: bounds: coprocessor segment overrun: invalid TSS: segment not present: invalid opcode: alignment check: stack segment: fpu exception: simd exception: iret exception: /var/log/messages -- /usr/bin/abrt-dump-oops -xtD
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The process `abrt-watch-log` takes strings to watch for and then runs a command. So what you're seeing as an error is just the strings to look for in `/var/log/messages`, which if found, is then sent to `/usr/bin/abrt-dump-oops`.

`$ man abrt-watch-log`:

```
NAME
       abrt-watch-log - Watch log file and run command when it grows or is replaced

SYNOPSIS
       abrt-watch-log [-vs] [-F STR] ... FILE PROG [ARGS]
```

Comment: Did you mean that the abrt-watch-log is OK and we have to look into /var/log/messages to find the real error?